# C# Multiple Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to build a Class that uses two Generic Types (both with constraints). Within that class is a property that is a list that uses both of those generic types. My issue is I would like some of the items in the list to use one model but others to use a different. Both of these models fit the constraints given to the class but I cannot find a way to allow me to do this. Let me provide the models and some code as an example

Models:

```
public class FeatureCollection<T, U> where T : BaseProperties where U : BaseGeometry
{
    public string name { get; set; } = "Name";
    public string type { get; set; } = "FeatureCollection";
    public List<Feature<T,U>> features { get; set; }
}
public class Feature<T, U> where T : BaseProperties where U : BaseGeometry
{
    public string type { get; set; } = "Feature";
    public U geometry { get; set; }
    public T properties { get; set; }
}

public class BaseGeometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}
public class BaseProperties
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class PolygonGeometry : BaseGeometry
{
    public PolygonGeometry()
    {
        type = "Polygon";
    }

    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; } = new List<List<List<double>>>();
}

public class PointGeometry : BaseGeometry
{
    public PointGeometry()
    {
        type = "Point";
    }
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; } = new List<double>();
}
```

Code:

```
List<Feature<WinterDataProperties, BaseGeometry>> features = new List<Feature<WinterDataProperties, BaseGeometry>>();

var PolygonGeometry = new Feature<WinterDataProperties, PolygonGeometry>
{
    geometry = new PolygonGeometry
    {
        coordinates = new List<List<List<double>>>() { new List<List<double>> { new List<double> { } } }
    }
};

//features.Add(PolygonGeometry);

var PointGeometry = new Feature<WinterDataProperties, PointGeometry>
{
    geometry = new PointGeometry
    {
        coordinates = new List<double> { }
    }
};

//features.Add(PointGeometry);

FeatureCollection<WinterDataProperties, BaseGeometry> collection = new FeatureCollection<WinterDataProperties, BaseGeometry> {
    features = features
};
```

As shown in the code I would like to add some items to my list of features with a Geometry type of PolygonGeometry and some with the type of PointGeometry. If anyone has any ideas on how I could build this list of features in the way I looking too that would be a huge help. Thank you!

Also, my core issue is because I need to define the coordinates properties as different types so I suppose if there was a way to allow that field to be either type that would also work as a solution to my issue.

Comment: Are you looking for covariance? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: I think that may work for me. I will give it a go and see. Actually, by doing it this way if say i try to filter the main list base on a property that exists in the derived class would i be able to? Like so
       ` var features = new List<Feature>();
            var feat = new Feature
            {
                properties = new WinterDataProperties
                {
                    Fips = "YO"
                }
            };
            features.Add(PolygonGeometry);
            features.Where(x => x.properties.Fips == "" );`

Comment: Sorry i kinda messed up that comment. Like so, 
            features.Where(x => x.properties.Fips == "" );
Where Fips is a property is exists in the derived class but not the Base class

Comment: You can use LINQ’s `.OfType<Derived>()` to filter for only matching derived instances, or `.Cast<Derived>()` if you know they are all of the derived type.